# Resolve quadratic equation

Tags: code-golf, math, complex-numbers

**Challenge:**

Write the smallest program (in characters) that resolves quadratic equations 
i.e. `ax² + bx + c = 0`

**Rules:**

Given 3 numbers in **R** comma-delimited on STDIN: a,b,c (a != 0),
print on STDOUT the 2 roots in **C**, one per line.

**R** stands for real numbers, **C** for complex numbers.

**Examples:**

```
Input         Output

1,0,0         r1=0     also accepted: r1=(-0-sqrt(0))/2
              r2=0

1,2,1         r1=-1    also accepted: r1=(-2-sqrt(0))/2
              r2=-1

1,1,1         r1=(-1-isqrt(3))/2  also accepted: r1=(-1-sqrt(-3))/2 or r1=-0.5-0.866i
              r2=(-1+isqrt(3))/2
```

Comment: What does `isqrt` mean? Are there any constraints on the output format (e.g. canonical forms) or is any expression which resolves to the roots valid?

Comment: @Peter Taylor: isqrt stands for i * squareRoot(3). The output have to be on 2 lines as shown in the output column of examples.

Comment: But would `r1=(-2-sqrt(0))/2` be an acceptable output line? How about `r1=(-1-sqrt(-3))/2` ?

Comment: @Peter Taylor: I see what you mean, yes both output are acceptable.

Comment: I implemented this using a Casio fx-7000G - http://www.rskey.org/detail.asp?manufacturer=Casio&model=fx-7000G - (not sure the extact model). I remember there being only 32 steps for a program and the version I came up with was 31 (including the data entry).

Answer (score 8):

**R, 19 chars**

```
polyroot(scan(n=3))
```

or more strictly following the I/O requirements in 58 chars:

```
r=polyroot(rev(scan(sep=",")));cat("r1=",r[1],"\nr2=",r[2])
```

edit: reversed coefficients

Comment: Great, now just format the output correctly too...

Comment: `cat(paste("r",1:2,"=",polyroot(rev(scan(se=",",qui=T))),sep=""),sep="\n")` You need to rev the coefficients (two of the three examples were palindromic, so it wasn't obvious).  Also, added `quiet=TRUE` to `scan` to suppress "Read 3 items" and shortened all arguments to minimum possible (which was `se` instead of `sep` for `scan`.

Answer (score 6):

## J, 21

J's got a verb to do exactly that: `p.`  It does complex to complex, but your problem is a subset of that.

```
echo"0>{:p.|.".1!:1[3
```

As always with J solutions here, I/O and formatting take up 90% of the solution.

Comment: Whoever downvoted this: why? If it's buggy, post a comment. If you have a problem with "challenges" which are solved in 1 character in a language which is used in the real world then downvote the question, not the answer.

Comment: @J B: Nice one, +1

Comment: It looks really nice, but I don't know if it follow the contest rules (load from stdin and output `r1=`)

Comment: @JBernardo: it follows the rules strictly as far as STDIN goes.  STDOUT is a bit more relaxed, but acceptable IMHO: it assumes interactive J, and outputs in a format different from the example, but that's in line with my interpretation of word "example"'s meaning.

Comment: Oh, I hadn't noticed the poster required one answer per line.  That at least I can fix easily.

Comment: There, fixed.  Noticed along the way that commas are already a perfectly acceptable vector separator, so that's a lot of useless characters down the drain. \o/

Comment: Could you perhaps post the output for those of us that don't have J?

Comment: @Tommy: J is freely available at [jsoftware.com](http://jsoftware.com/stable.htm), but I'll edit anyway.

Answer (score 4):

### Python 3, 79 chars

```python
a,b,c=eval(input())
d=(b*b-4*a*c)**.5/2/a
x=-b/2/a
print('r1=',x+d,'\nr2=',x-d)
```

Python's imaginary unity is `j` and not `i`. I used Python 3 because the power operator works also on negative numbers.

BTW, is it really needed to write `r1= ...` and `r2= ...` ?

Comment: +1, It's OK for `j` instead of `i`. `r1=` is part of the challenge.

Comment: Nine years later, with the new walrus operator, the formula can be shortened to `[p:=b/2+(b*b/4-a*c)**.5/a,b-p]`, and with formatting strings, the output can just be `'r1='+str(p:=b/2+(b*b/4-a*c)**.5/a)+f'\nr2={b-p}'` (walrus operator doesn't work inside formatting strings), saving you 4 characters.

Answer (score 1):

### Perl, <strike>96</strike> 87 Characters

```
($a,$b,$c)=eval<>;$_=abs($_=$b*$b-4*$a*$c)**.5/2/$a.i x($_<0);$b/=-2*$a;die"r1=$b+$_
r2=$b-$_"
```

The line break is intentional, as is a space.

Edit: By reformatting output, I can shorten this to:

```
($a,$b,$c)=eval<>;$_="sqrt(".($b*$b-4*$a*$c)."))/".2*$a;$b*=-1;die"r1=($b+$_
r2=($b-$_"
```

Answer (score 1):

### Perl, 76 characters (+1 command line switch)

```
perl -pe '($a,$b,$c)=eval;$d=($b/=-$a)**2-4*$c/$a;$_="-+";s!.!r@+=($b$&sqrt($d))/2\n!g'
```

Replacing the `\n` with a literal newline allows a further trivial one-character reduction.

Sample input / output:

```
1,0,0
r1=(0-sqrt(0))/2
r2=(0+sqrt(0))/2
1,2,1
r1=(-2-sqrt(0))/2
r2=(-2+sqrt(0))/2
1,1,1
r1=(-1-sqrt(-3))/2
r2=(-1+sqrt(-3))/2
1,0,-1
r1=(0-sqrt(4))/2
r2=(0+sqrt(4))/2
2,1,1
r1=(-0.5-sqrt(-1.75))/2
r2=(-0.5+sqrt(-1.75))/2
```

Yeah, it's not exactly Wolfram Alpha, but I believe it should qualify as acceptable output.

Answer (score 0):

## Perl, 101 chars

First stab:

```
perl -E 'my($x,$y,$z)=pop=~/\d+/g;printf"r%d=(%+d%ssqrt(%d))/%d\n",++$p,-$y,$_,$y**2-4*$x*$z,2*$x for qw/- +/;' 1,2,1
```

Comment: The last `$x` in `printf` should be `$x*2`, and last double quote `"` a single one `'`

Comment: @M42 : Right. Bitten by the Windows `""` issue again.

Answer (score 0):

### D (160 chars)

```
import std.complex;import std.stdio;void main(){real a,b,c;readf("%f,%f,%f",&a,&b,&c);Complex!real j=sqrt(b*b-4*a*c)/2/a,i=-b/2/a;write("r1=",i+j,"\nr2=",i-j);}
```